# Couldn't access value of variable in AsyncTask from onReceive

Tags: android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

I have a Class (BroadcastReceiver) as

```
public class AlarmReceiverActivity extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

         public  String memtypefrommainactivity="";

         Context mContext;

@Override

  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)

 {

  context=mContext;

  memtypefrommainactivity = intent.getStringExtra("memtypetobroadcast");

 new CheckNewMessages(context).execute(memtypefrommainactivity);

}

And in the same class I have one Asynctask :

protected class CheckNewMessages extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        public CheckNewMessages(Context context)
        {
            mContext=context;
        }

@Override

protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        public String doInBackground(String... params)
 {

 if(memtypefrommainactivity=="Retired".toString())

{

URL="xyz.com";

}
```

I didn't get the value of `memtypefrommainactivity` from both reference  `memtypefrommainactivity` and `params[0]`.

Comment: memtypefrommainactivity = intent.getStringExtra("memtypetobroadcast");
in this line ,are you getting something ?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the value. But I couldn't pass it to AsyncTask.The value is not available in AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

A `BroadcastReceiver` has an extremely short lifetime. Basically after `onReceive()` returns, the `BroadcastReceiver` is dead. As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)), you cannot start asynchronous or long-running activities from a `BroadcastReceiver` and expect to get any callbacks. You need to use a `Service` instead of `AsyncTask`. Your `BroadcastReceiver` should start a `Service` to do the work, passing it the necessary parameters. Youc an probably do away with the `BroadcastReceiver` entirely and just have the `AlarmManager` start the `Service` directly.

Comment: in onReceive() , I am getting value from intent.getStringExtra("memtypetobroadcast"); but i couldn't pass it to Async Task. if I didn't check it works smoothly. The only portion if(memtypefrommainactivity=="Retired".toString()) isn't working, because the value of memtypefrommainactivity is null

Comment: I do not understand your comment. In any case, you should not compare strings using '=='. Use `"Retired".equals(memtypefrommainactivity)` instead.